# EF Core 3.1 Intellisense not displaying table columns in Where clause of Linq statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm migrating an existing application from Asp.net Core 2.2 to Asp.net Core 3.1, and am having to fix some Linq statements that query data from a SQL server database. I notice that when I add a "Where" or "Select" clause to the Linq statement and begin writing my lambda expression, the intellisense does not provide the  column names when I use dot notation on the table parameter.

screenshot of intellisense using EF Core 3.1

[image: screenshot of intellisense using EF Core 3.1]
I can manually type the column names and the code compiles just fine, but that gets tedious and is prone to type-o's. Not sure if I need to configure Visual Studio differently to get this to work, or if there is another solution out there to fix this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[screenshot of intellisense using Asp.net Core 2.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idR3P.png)

Comment: It is showing properties, but the problem is that these are not the properties for the "PortalClientUserMap" entity. The properties it's showing are for the "System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression" class.

Comment: I'm seeing this same issue in my AutoMapper profile maps, so I'm thinking it may be an issue with Linq, and not exclusive to EF Core. Still looking for a solution, if anyone has any ideas.

Comment: What type does Intellisense think `x` is?

Comment: System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression

Comment: I am thinking you have found a VS bug and should report it to Microsoft.